# have many images with one object

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have one UIImageView object. With this one object I need to set 12 frames and 12 images. with one object.
How?

```
UIImageView *obj = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

[obj setFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,50,56)];

[obj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"x"]];
```

this is one image and frame declaration with one object. Like this I need to add 12 images and frames with one object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method: `[UIImageView setAnimationImages:]`.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to animate? or are you trying to show 12 images simultaneously?  If you are trying to animate use GameBit's answer.  If you are trying to show 12 images simultaneously you need 12 UIImageView objects.  If you want to keep them all together you can add them to a single UIView.  Think of it like a container for your ImageViews.